# Django redirecting in urls.py to another url

Tags: python, django, url

I have this code in my urls.py

```
(r'^some/page/', RedirectView.as_view(url='http://google.com'))
```

why doesn't it go to google when I cleck the link ?

Comment: What is the `href` in your link?

Comment: Can you show us your view? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview

Comment: That is the view, you can do this in urls.py.  I just added `url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url='http://google.com'))` to my urls.py and it worked fine.  What is actaully happening in your app?  Is the url pattern actually getting a match?