# How to apply 301 redirect in urls.py in django

Tags: python, django

I want to redirect my old url to new url .http://www.cancleanpressurewashers.com/
to http://royturk.macraesdev.com/services/shop-service-repair/ . Here this will be redirected to different domain.

Comment: Sounds like a great job for the webserver before Django.

Comment: @KlausD. can you please elaborate ??

Comment: Refer this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23113902/django-redirecting-in-urls-py-to-another-url#comment35334639_23113902

Comment: You can always use a middleware. Look at http://eikke.com/django-domain-redirect-middleware/index.html (it's an old piece of code, might involve a bit of work)

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this by simply redirecting in your view that corresponds to the `/` url:

```
class YourView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        redirect("http://royturk.macraesdev.com/services/shop-service-repair/")
```

But I think that the better way of doing it would be with a web server such Nginx. In nginx, you could do this by adding anoter `server` block to your config:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name http://www.cancleanpressurewashers.com/ 
   return 301 http://royturk.macraesdev.com/services/shop-service-repair/
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I am new to python    can you point where config file is located in Nginx rite now I am having FTP access .

Comment: @owt are you using Nginx?

Comment: @owt if you are using Ubuntu or a similar distro, it is you should create a file in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/your-config-file`

Comment: rite now I have access to FTP so is it possible to get this file in these directories or not ?

Comment: @owt I don't think so. If don't have access, just go with the first option and redirect inside the django itself

Comment: class YourView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        redirect("http://royturk.macraesdev.com/services/shop-service-repair/") can you let me know where to add this code if I opt second method.